# First MIPS program

Tags: mips

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the following mathematical equation: A = B + C.
B must be stored in memory, while C in a register.

So far I have done the following, but it doesn't work:

```
.set noreorder
.data 
    b: .word 20
    c: .word 10
.text
.globl main
.ent main

main:
    la $t0, b
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    la $t1, c
    lw $a1, 0($t1)
    add $t9, $a0, $a1
.end main
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How "does it not work"? What error message or unexpected results do you get?

Comment: I get "ERROR: Illegal operands 'la'". Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like the `la` mnemonic is not being recognized. What assembler?

Comment: So you are saying that the code is correct? Would you not solve this differently?

Comment: The code does not look unreasonable. The syntax of assembly code can vary from assembler to assembler. Check your reference manual carefully to ensure you are using the correct mnemonics : `la`, `lw` etc. I have found not good reference to any assembler called `mipslt`

Comment: By the way, how would you store a variable in memory, and how in register? I confuse the 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.set noreorder
.data 
    B: .word 20
    C: .word 10
.text
.globl main
.ent main

main:
    la $t0, B
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    la $t1, C
    lw $a1, 0($t1)
    add $t9, $a0, $a1
.end main
```

I have changed your code to use upper-case labels. This is because when I ran your code in the `spim` simulator I got this error: `spim: (parser) Cannot use opcodes as labels on line 7 of file test.s`.

`b` is actually the name of an instruction, so changing the names of the labels fixed the code for me.